# set-like products of ranges for queries etc

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a nice way to write something like this:

```
foreach ((i,j) in PRODUCTOF(Range1, Range2))
```

or

```
PRODUCTOF(Range1, Range2).Sum((i,j) => i+17*j)
```

where PRODUCTOF is the unknown thing to me.

Of course, you could circumvent this or write a function for this, but maybe there is a build-in syntax that one should prefer.

Comment: yes, the cartesian product of two ranges, to be indexed in a mathematical way as (i,j) or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SelectMany` is too verbose you could always write an extension I suppose, somthing like,

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T,T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
            this IEnumerable<T> source,
            IEnumerable<T> multiplier)
    {
        return source.SelectMany(s => multiplier, (s, m) => Tuple.Create(s, m));   
    }
}
```

which you could use like

```
Range1.CartesianProduct(Range2).Sum(p => p.item1+17*p.item2);
```

but, I'm not sure you'd gain that much. As you suggest, you could take it a step further,

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> CartesianProduct<T, TResult>(
            this IEnumerable<T> source,
            IEnumerable<T> multiplier,
            Func<T, T, TResult> combiner)
    {
        return source.SelectMany(s => multiplier, (s, m) => combiner(s, m));   
    }
}
```

and use like this,

```
Range1.CartesianProduct(Range2, (x, y) => x+17*y).Sum();
```

which does look somewhat neater.

---

either way, the credit goes to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11684264/659190) for providing the window I've dressed.

Answer (score 4):

You mean something like:

```
foreach (var pair in Range1.SelectMany(x => Range2, (x, y) => new { x, y }))
{
    // Use pair.x and pair.y
}
```

Or for your `Sum` example:

```
var sum = Range1.SelectMany(x => Range2, (x, y) => new { x, y })
                .Sum(pair => pair.x + pair.y * 17);
```

As a query expression:

```
var query = from x in Range1
            from y in Range2
            select new { x, y };
var sum = query.Sum(pair => pair.x + pair.y * 17);
```

This is assuming you want the cross-product - every possibly pair. If you're only trying to form pairs of `{ Range1(0), Range2(0) }, { Range1(1), Range2(1) }` etc then you should use `Zip` instead.

Comment: Thank you; I hoped for something shorter and easier to read, since I have a lot of complicated formulae, which are summed over two ranges. I think I use a function like DoubleSum(Range1, Range2, Func<int,int,double>).